# Динамическое объявление роутов в LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, route

Вопрос по части LARAVEL

В файле web.php есть такие роуты:

```
# Страницы
Route::resources(['articles'    => ArticlesController::class]);
# Мероприятия
Route::resources(['events'      => EventsController::class]);
# Календарь
Route::resources(['calendar'    => CalendarController::class]);
```

Мне нужно их объявить динамично, например так:

```
$ClassArray['articles'] = 'ArticlesController';
$ClassArray['events'] = 'EventsController';
$ClassArray['calendar'] = 'CalendarController';

foreach($ClassArray as $mod=>$class){
    Route::resources([$mod => $class::class]);      
}
```

Разумеется "$class::class" выдает ошибку.

Как это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` раскомментируйте строку (примерно 29-30 строка):

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

В файле роутов в таком случае можно использовать старый вариант написания контроллеров через строки.

В Вашем случае это будет так:

```
$ClassArray = [
    'articles' => 'ArticlesController',
    'events' => 'EventsController',
    'calendar' => 'CalendarController',
];

Route::resources($ClassArray);
```

Comment: Такой вариант работает, но после раскомментирования этой строки другие роуты перестают работать. Похожу мне нужен смешанный вариант.

Comment: @ПетрСкотар Ну так можете поправить до относительного пути. Или у Вас что-то настолько специфичное, что контроллеры хранятся вне папки `app/Http/Controllers`?

Comment: Да, вы правы. Если остальные роуты поправить до относительного пути, то все работает.. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать таким образом, должно работать:

```
$ClassArray['articles'] = ArticlesController::class;
$ClassArray['events']   = EventsController::class;
$ClassArray['calendar'] = CalendarController::class;

foreach($ClassArray as $mod=>$class){
    Route::resources([$mod => $class]);      
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что имена контроллеров у меня хранятся в конфих.файлах, как строка 'ArticlesController'. Т.е. я их вытаскиваю с файла конфигурации и прописываю в массив $ClassArray. Это свого роду как включение/отключение модулей через файл конфиг, а не закоментирование в файле роутов